# Problemas para crear un loop

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x0,xtengo,x1,y0,yhallar,y1;
    char respuesta;
    bool repetir= true;
    int condicion;
    while(repetir){
    cout << "Este programa te permite interpolar asi: " << endl;
    cout<<"|   X   |    Y    |"<<endl;
    cout<<"|   X0  |    Y0   |"<<endl;
    cout<<"|   Xt  |    Yh   |"<<endl;
    cout<<"|   X1  |    Y1   |"<<endl;
    cout<<"Ingresa el valor de X0:";
    cin>>x0;
    cout<<"Ingresa el valor de X1:";
    cin>>x1;
     cout<<"Ingresa el valor de Y0:";
    cin>>y0;
     cout<<"Ingresa el valor de Y1:";
    cin>>y1;
     cout<<"Ingresa el valor de Xt para hallar Yh:";
    cin>>xtengo;
    yhallar=y0+(((y1-y0)/(x1-x0))*(xtengo-x0));
    cout<<"\nEl valor de la interpolacion es: "<<yhallar<<endl;
    cout<<"\nDesea hacer otra interpolacion?(si(1)/no(2))";
    cin>>condicion;
    if(condicion==1)
        {
        repetir=true;
        }
    else
        {
        repetir=false;
        }
     return 0;
    }
}
```

Hola, la verdad soy muy nuevo en este mundo de la programacion nuevo es muy nuevo la y ademas aprendo a puro video de youtube, pero en clases me serviria mucho este programa, alguien me podria decir porque no se repite el loop, ya trate varias cosas, imagino que mi error es muy obvio pero no lo veo ayudaaaaa, gracias :)

EDIT: ya Christian me ayudo es por el return dentro el while.

Comment: no se repite por que el `return 0;` está dentro del `while`

Comment: Si identas el código notarás más fácil este tipo de errores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola te he dejado algunos comentarios en el código, espero los comentarios te puedan ser útiles en códigos futuros. Tu principal problema es la mala ubicación de la linea de código "return 0"

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        double x0,xtengo,x1,y0,yhallar,y1;
        char respuesta;
        bool repetir= true;
        int condicion;
        while(repetir==true){ //Aquí debes establecer la condición para que el while se cumpla
        cout << "Este programa te permite interpolar asi: " << endl;
        cout<<"|   X   |    Y    |"<<endl;
        cout<<"|   X0  |    Y0   |"<<endl;
        cout<<"|   Xt  |    Yh   |"<<endl;
        cout<<"|   X1  |    Y1   |"<<endl;
        cout<<"Ingresa el valor de X0:";
        cin>>x0;
        cout<<"Ingresa el valor de X1:";
        cin>>x1;
         cout<<"Ingresa el valor de Y0:";
        cin>>y0;
         cout<<"Ingresa el valor de Y1:";
        cin>>y1;
         cout<<"Ingresa el valor de Xt para hallar Yh:";
        cin>>xtengo;
        yhallar=y0+(((y1-y0)/(x1-x0))*(xtengo-x0));
        cout<<"\nEl valor de la interpolacion es: "<<yhallar<<endl;
        cout<<"\nDesea hacer otra interpolacion?(si(1)/no(2))";

        cin>>condicion;
        if(condicion==1)
            {
            repetir=true;
            }
        else
            {
                //Por ejemplo aquí puede ejecutar el return 0; para que cuando el usuario seleccione no repetir, entonces el programa finaliza inmediatamente
                //Sin tener en cuenta cualquier linea de código abajo del return 0;
             //en vez de repetir = false puedes escribir  return 0;
            repetir=false;
            }
        }

        return 0;// Al ubicación del return 0 es una linea antes de la llave de cierre de la función int main(), 
        //si quieres tambien puedes omitir el return 0, este solo se ocupa cuando quieres que el programa finalice antes de llegar a la
        //última linea de código del int main
    }
```

Es bueno que tu código sea ordenado y bien tabulado, así se te hace mas fácil identificar los errores y las posibles soluciones.

Comment: Muchas Gracias.